# XSL font issue - FOP

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I'm receiving this error below from a template I created

```
WARNING: Font "Calibri,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".


xsl attribute created

<xsl:attribute-set name="common">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-family">Calibri</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">regular</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

I'm using Windows 10 and I see that I have Calibri regular installed on this machine. I'm unclear on why this wouldn't be recognized and substituted with any. Any ideas?

Here is the fop.xconf

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- $Id: fop.xconf 1616312 2014-08-06 19:19:31Z gadams $ -->

<!--

This is an example configuration file for FOP.
This file contains the same settings as the default values
and will have no effect if used unchanged.

Relative config url's will be resolved relative to
the location of this file.

-->

<!-- NOTE: This is the version of the configuration -->
<fop version="1.0">

  <!-- Base URL for resolving relative URLs -->
  <base>.</base>
  
  <!-- Source resolution in dpi (dots/pixels per inch) for determining the size of pixels in SVG and bitmap images, default: 72dpi -->
  <source-resolution>72</source-resolution>
  <!-- Target resolution in dpi (dots/pixels per inch) for specifying the target resolution for generated bitmaps, default: 72dpi -->
  <target-resolution>72</target-resolution>
  
  <!-- Default page-height and page-width, in case value is specified as auto -->
  <default-page-settings height="11.00in" width="8.50in"/>
  
  <!-- Information for specific renderers -->
  <!-- Uses renderer mime type for renderers -->
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <filterList>
        <!-- provides compression using zlib flate (default is on) -->
        <value>flate</value>
  
      </filterList>

      <fonts>

    
        <auto-detect/>

      </fonts>

  

    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="application/x-afp">
      <!--
           The bit depth and type of images produced
           (this is the default setting)
      -->
      <images mode="b+w" bits-per-pixel="8"/>
      <renderer-resolution>240</renderer-resolution>
      <line-width-correction>2.5</line-width-correction>
      <resource-group-file>resources.afp</resource-group-file>

      <fonts>
     


        <!-- Times Roman -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Times Roman" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0N20060" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0N20070" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0N20080" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0N20090" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0N20000" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0N200A0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0N200B0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0N200D0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0N200F0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0N200H0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0N200J0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0N200N0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0N200T0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0N200Z0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesRoman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times Roman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times-Roman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
 
        <!-- Times Roman Italic -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Times Roman Italic" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0N30060" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0N30070" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0N30080" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0N30090" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0N30000" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0N300A0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0N300B0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0N300D0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0N300F0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0N300H0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0N300J0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0N300N0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0N300T0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0N300Z0" base14-font="TimesItalic"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesRoman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times Roman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times-Roman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="serif" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
 
        <!-- Times Roman Bold -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Times Roman Bold" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0N40060" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0N40070" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0N40080" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0N40090" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0N40000" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0N400A0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0N400B0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0N400D0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0N400F0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0N400H0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0N400J0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0N400N0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0N400T0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0N400Z0" base14-font="TimesBold"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesRoman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times Roman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times-Roman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="serif" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Times Roman Italic Bold -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Times Roman Italic Bold" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0N50060" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0N50070" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0N50080" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0N50090" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0N50000" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0N500A0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0N500B0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0N500D0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0N500F0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0N500H0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0N500J0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0N500N0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0N500T0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0N500Z0" base14-font="TimesBoldItalic"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesRoman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times Roman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times-Roman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="serif" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Helvetica -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Helvetica" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0H20060" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0H20070" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0H20080" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0H20090" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0H20000" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0H200A0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0H200B0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0H200D0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0H200F0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0H200H0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0H200J0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0H200N0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0H200T0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0H200Z0" base14-font="Helvetica"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="any" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Helvetica Italic -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Helvetica Italic" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0H30060" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0H30070" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0H30080" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0H30090" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0H30000" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0H300A0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0H300B0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0H300D0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0H300F0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0H300H0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0H300J0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0H300N0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0H300T0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0H300Z0" base14-font="HelveticaOblique"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="Arial" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Helvetica (Semi) Bold -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Helvetica (Semi) Bold" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0H40060" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0H40070" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0H40080" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0H40090" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0H40000" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0H400A0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0H400B0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0H400D0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0H400F0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0H400H0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0H400J0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0H400N0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0H400T0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0H400Z0" base14-font="HelveticaBold"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Helvetica Italic (Semi) Bold -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Helvetica Italic (Semi) Bold" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0H50060" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0H50070" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0H50080" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0H50090" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0H50000" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0H500A0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0H500B0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0H500D0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0H500F0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0H500H0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0H500J0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0H500N0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0H500T0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0H500Z0" base14-font="HelveticaBoldOblique"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Helvetica" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="Arial" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="sans-serif" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Courier -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Courier" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0420060" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0420070" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0420080" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0420090" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0420000" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C04200A0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C04200B0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C04200D0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C04200F0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C04200H0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C04200J0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C04200N0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C04200T0" base14-font="Courier"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C04200Z0" base14-font="Courier"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="monospace" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Courier Italic -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Courier Italic" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0430060" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0430070" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0430080" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0430090" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0430000" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C04300A0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C04300B0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C04300D0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C04300F0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C04300H0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C04300J0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C04300N0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C04300T0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C04300Z0" base14-font="CourierOblique"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
          <font-triplet name="monospace" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Courier Bold -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Courier Bold" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0440060" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0440070" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0440080" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0440090" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0440000" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C04400A0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C04400B0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C04400D0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C04400F0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C04400H0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C04400J0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C04400N0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C04400T0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C04400Z0" base14-font="CourierBold"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="monospace" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
        </font>

        <!-- Courier Italic Bold -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Courier Italic Bold" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
            <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0450060" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0450070" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0450080" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0450090" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0450000" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C04500A0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C04500B0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C04500D0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C04500F0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C04500H0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C04500J0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C04500N0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C04500T0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
            <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C04500Z0" base14-font="CourierBoldOblique"/>
          </afp-font>
          <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
          <font-triplet name="monospace" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
        </font>
        
         <!-- 
        Configure double-byte (CID Keyed font (Type 0)) AFP fonts with type="CIDKeyed".  
        
        example:
         <font>
                <afp-font type="CIDKeyed" encoding="UnicodeBigUnmarked"  
                codepage="T1120000" characterset="CZJHMNU" 
                base-uri="fonts" />
                <font-triplet name="J-Heisei Mincho" style="normal" weight="normal" />
         </font>
        -->
        
        
      </fonts>
    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="application/postscript">
      <!-- This option forces the PS renderer to rotate landscape pages -->
      <!--auto-rotate-landscape>true</auto-rotate-landscape-->
      
      <!-- This option lets you specify additional options on an XML handler -->
      <!--xml-handler namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <stroke-text>false</stroke-text>
      </xml-handler-->
    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="application/vnd.hp-PCL">
    </renderer>

    <!-- MIF does not have a renderer
    <renderer mime="application/vnd.mif">
    </renderer>
    -->

    <renderer mime="image/svg+xml">
      <format type="paginated"/>
      <link value="true"/>
      <strokeText value="false"/>
    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="application/awt">
    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="image/png">
      <!--transparent-page-background>true</transparent-page-background-->
    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="image/tiff">
      <!--transparent-page-background>true</transparent-page-background-->
      <!--compression>CCITT T.6</compression-->
    </renderer>

    <renderer mime="text/xml">
    </renderer>

    <!-- RTF does not have a renderer
    <renderer mime="text/rtf">
    </renderer>
    -->

  </renderers>

</fop>
```

Above is the fop.xconf folder that shows it autodetects locally for PDF, but I don't get why I would receive that error even though Win10 has a local Calibri font pack.

Comment: Have you configured FOP at all to look for system fonts?

Comment: I have not. I am using FOP-2.5 and thought this was configured to already look at system fonts. Where would I configure this setting? thank you.

Comment: The only issue I see in your XSL is the use of `regular` for `font-weight`, I think the right value would be `normal`. But as FOP says it looks for `Calibri,normal,700` this doesn't seem to be the issue, somehow your configuration with the autodetect doesn't seem to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Set `<auto-detect/>` in the configuration file e.g.

```
<renderers>
  <renderer mime="application/pdf">
     <fonts>

        <!-- automatically detect operating system installed fonts -->
        <auto-detect/>
     </fonts>
  </renderer>
</renderers>
```

Comment: I have auto-detect already enabled in the <fonts> section in the FOP.

Comment: @MrPeachyPenguin, consider to edit your question and show us exactly how you configure and run FOP. Does it find other Windows fonts?

Comment: in the original question I attached the fop.xconf

Comment: @MrPeachyPenguin, you will also need to detail how you use or call FOP, otherwise nobody can tell whether the configuration file is used. Also, as asked before, with your setup, does FOP use other Windows fonts?